# ERROR in prerender.ts(7,62): error TS2307: Cannot find module './dist-prerender/main.bundle'

Tags: angular, typescript, prerender

While I am compiling the angular code for prerendering below error is coming

> ERROR in prerender.ts(7,62): error TS2307: Cannot find module './dist-prerender/main.bundle'

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! XXXX@2.0.0 build: `ng build && ng build --project prerender --output-hashing=none`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the XXXXX@2.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-06-12T07_43_21_717Z-debug.log
```

Maybe my application not able to generate the main.bundle file

For prerendering I have added some code in angular.json

> angular.json

```
"prerender" : {

        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "projectType": "application",
        "prefix": "app",
        "schematics": {},
        "architect": {
                "build": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist-prerender",
                        "main": "main.prerender.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.prerender.json"
                },
                        "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                                "fileReplacements": [
                                        {
                                         "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                         "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "optimization": true,
                                "outputHashing": "all",
                                "sourceMap": false,
                                "extractCss": true,
                                "namedChunks": false,
                                "aot": true,
                                "extractLicenses": true,
                                "vendorChunk": false,
                                "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                }}
                }`
```

> tsconfig.prerender.json

```
  {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/prerender",
    /* node only understands commonjs for now*/
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.prerender.module#AppPrerenderModule"
  }
}
```

Comment: which angular version were you using here ?

Answer (score 0):

While the command `ng build --project prerender --output-hashing=none` was executed, `webpack.server.config.js` and `prerender.ts` these files also got executed which was throwing an error for me. To get rid of this error I simply executed `ng build --project prerender --output-hashing=none` this command first and then added the `prerender.ts` file after the compilation of that command.